# What is the proper way to use the Model in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, opencart

Can you help me with this? I am currently studying Laravel on my own and I followed the tutorials in the Laracasts and it is awesome. Before Laravel I am using CodeIgniter and Opencart in my projects and I started to study Laravel because I want to learn a new framework.

In CI and Opencart all your database queries are in the model. But in Laravel you can perform and queries in Controller?. Is it a proper way to the queries in Laravel?

I have this kind of code in the Controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use App\Article;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ArticlesController extends Controller {

    public function index() {

        $articles = Article::all();

        return view('articles.index')->with('articles', $articles);

    }

}
```

Comment: If you have account in laracasts, look this: https://laracasts.com/search?q=repositories&q-where=lessons

Comment: Another one: http://ryantablada.com/post/the-repository-pattern-in-action

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Repositories is a smart decision to you. But why?**
Basically, repositories is a 'gateway' between your application and your storage.
With repositories, you'll find your 'database queries' in a single place.

**Let's think about the model Articles.**
Instead of use a static instance of Articles all the times that you need to use it (`Articles::find()`, `Articles::all()`, etc), just create a repository of Articles.
Inject this repo in your controller (e.g.), and use 'features' storaged in your ArticleRepository.

**What do you mean?**
Let's consider a repository of Articles. What I'll use many times in my app of Articles model? I need select all, select by id, insert, update, delete. Basically these 'stuffs'. So, if I have all this stuffs in a place?

```
class ArticleRepository {

    public function all(){}
    public function getById($id){}
    public function insert($data){}
    public function update($data){}
    public function delete($id){}

}
```

Inject this ArticleRepository in your controller. To do this, read a about IoC Container here: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container

The construct in your controller will be like this:

```
public function __construct(ArticleRepository $articles)
{
    $this->articles = $articles;
}
```

Once all, when you need get all Articles in your controller, just do:

```
public function index()
{
    $articles = $this->articles->all();
    return View::make('articles.index')->with(['articles' => $articles]);
}
```

With this practice, you have a clean application with testables controllers and a beautiful organization and design.  ;)

Look, I tried to be as didactic as possible to you understand the concept. The use of repositories is not only a way to do. So I let the links in the comments. And let other references here as well.
I'm sure you will understand quickly.
Success in learning! :)

https://laracasts.com/search?q=repositories&q-where=lessons
http://ryantablada.com/post/the-repository-pattern-in-action
http://culttt.com/2014/03/17/eloquent-tricks-better-repositories/
http://culttt.com/2013/07/15/how-to-structure-testable-controllers-in-laravel-4/

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation about that. I will check your reference links too. :)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is perfectly fine for small applications.
For large-scale apps however, i'd recommend using repositories as they decouple your models from the controller - which makes them more readable and testable.

Your ArticlesController would translate to something like this:

```php
<?php namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Repositories\Articles\ArticleRepositoryInterface;

class ArticlesController extends Controller {

    private $articles;

    public function __construct(ArticleRepositoryInterface $articles)
    {
        $this->articles = $articles;
    }

    public function index()
    {
        return view('articles.index')
            ->with('articles', $this->articles->all());
    }

}
```

Have a look at Laravels [Service Container](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/container) to understand the automatic resolution of the *ArticleRepositoryInterface*. [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/search?q=repositories&q-where=lessons) has some good videos on repositories.